# Error al instalar Prestashop en VPS

Tags: prestashop, vps, prestashop1.7

Estoy tratando de instalar Prestashop 1.7.5.1 en un servidor adquirido en Hostinger, usando estos tutoriales se ha configurado el servidor y se ha creado la cuenta FTP

```
https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-vps/
https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/ssh/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys
```

Lo que sucede es que al llegar al paso #6 del siguiente articulo que es la instalación de la plataforma:

```
https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-install-prestashop-on-ubuntu-18-04-server/
```

Dice ingresar http://ip-address/ para comenzar la instalación, a mi me muestra un error en el explorador al ingresar con mi IP>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota*: Yo aun no cuento con un dominio que apunte hacia el VPS, no se si ese sea el problema.

Tengo entendido que el VPS cuenta con una IP que es con la que se puede acceder por SSH y FTP, con esa misma IP debería poderse instalar Prestashop no?

Alguien me da una idea de lo que podría ser el problema?

Comment: Permiteme agregarla a respuestas, gracias BetaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque es algo que se resolvio desde hace mucho tiempo, lo correcto era verificar que los Nameservers de mi hosting provider apuntaran a mi IP o que tuviera un A record en mis DNS apuntando a mi IP.

Parece ser que Prestashop busca la carpeta de resources a partir del nombre de dominio configurado en la tabla Ps_Shop.

Comment: Gracias @Nor por compartir la solucion a tu problema.
Y a veces es más habitual de lo que esperamos.

Answer (score 2):

depende de muchas cosas
1 tienes habilitado el servidor web,
2 no esta siendo utilizado por otro puerto el servidor php?
3 verifica si coincide el puerto con el que trae ubunto
4 intenta instalar en hostinger el Xampp en Ubuntu (https://www.sololinux.es/instalar-xampp-en-ubuntu-20-04-y-otros-linux/)

una vez que tengas todo eso debes de tener una pagina de inicio de bienvenida a xammp, cuando veas esa web de inicio ya puedes montar pretashop, hasta que no la veas el server web no esta disponible.

Answer (score 2):

En el paso 5 en los permisos, yo uso lo siguiente en diferentes servidores con Prestashop 1.7

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

y

```
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www/html/
```

También puedes verificar el estado de los servicios de apache `sudo systemctl status apache2`